# Playframework Java validation issue

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Given the following class:

```
class Foo{
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    public Timestamp getCreatedOn() {
        return this.createdOn;
    }  
}
```

and the following controller action method:

```
public Result post(){
  Form<Foo> form = request.bindFromRequest();
  if(form.hasErrors()){                
    return badRequest(views.html.formview(form));
  }else{
    doSomethingAwesome(form.get());
  }
}
```

and the following view

```
@form(routes.fooController.post(), 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role -> "form") {
            @inputText(
                form("createdDate"),
                '_label -> "Create Date",

            )
}
```

When I fill in the textbox with a date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy, it is still throwing a form validation errror and not binding to a timestamp.

What is the proper way to bind to a timestamp and not have the form helper throw a validation error?

Answer (score 0):

The "Form form = request.bindFromRequest();" fetchs the information on the request and binds it to Foo, try printing the value of form.createdOn, it's probably null and you have the flag "nullable = false" and it fails validation.